# Upgrade fullcalendar to version 6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

We are trying to upgrade fullcalendar v.6 (React) at the resource prop in <FullCalendar is gone, and I can't find in the documentation how to add the resources to the calendar object. We use typescript.

```
<FullCalendar
      resources={resourceList} ...>
```

No overload matches this call.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-data), `resources` is only available in the premium version of fullCalendar. Are you using the premium version? If not, that will be why the property doesn't exist. It was premium in earlier versions too, so it's unclear why you're having an issue only when you upgrade, unless you've simply not included the right modules in your v6 application.

Comment: There is a "FullCalendar Premium" section in the [fullcalendar react component documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react) which can guide you on this.

Comment: We are using the premium version but resources is still not a part of the props

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions in the second documentation link I provided? If so, and you still have a problem, please raise it with the maintainers of the fullcalendar react component, making sure to provide them with a provable example of the issue.